# Ember.js: Where does this method go?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Coming to Ember from Rails, one of the places I'm struggling is trying to figure out Ember's definitions of models, views, and controllers.

I'm just testing out some sample Ember code. I'm getting my user events via the GitHub API, and I want to change the type name into something readable.

I have a jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/UgOLujiF/1/), but here's the gist:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Ember.$.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/thenickcox/events').then(function(data){
      return data.splice(0,7);
    });
  }
});
```

I have a method that types a type and returns a string:

```
 interpretType: function(type){
    if (type === 'PushEvent') {
      return 'Pushed';
    }
    return name;
  }
```

In Rails, this would go on the model. But the only model here is the one that Ember created in memory by default (right?). So then I thought, it's something that each member of the array needs, because here's the view:

```
<h3> Some events</h3>
<ul>
{{#each}}
  <li>I {{interpretType(type)}} to {{repo.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

So is that something that goes on `Ember.ArrayController`? I tried that, like this:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  interpretType: function(type){
    if (type === 'PushEvent') {
      return 'Pushed';
    }
    return name;
  }.property()
});
```

That just gave me an error. Where do I put this?

PS. So you don't have to look at the GitHub API, here's an example JSON object:

```
{
id: "1890853674",
type: "CreateEvent",
actor: {
id: 702327,
login: "thenickcox",
gravatar_id: "63f35d9e50dfd73281126b051a51668a",
url: "https://api.github.com/users/thenickcox",
avatar_url: "https://2.gravatar.com/avatar/63f35d9e50dfd73281126b051a51668a?d=https%3A%2F%2Fa248.e.akamai.net%2Fassets.github.com%2Fimages%2Fgravatars%2Fgravatar-user-420.png&r=x"
},
repo: {
id: 14463966,
name: "thenickcox/whiskey_taster",
url: "https://api.github.com/repos/thenickcox/whiskey_taster"
},
payload: {
ref: "master",
ref_type: "branch",
master_branch: "master",
description: "My first ember/rails app"
},
public: true,
created_at: "2013-11-17T09:00:17Z"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/UgOLujiF/3)

Basically, the `each` can specify an itemController to decorate the model.

```
App.EventController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  interpretType: function(){
    var type = this.get('model.type');
    if (type === 'PushEvent') {
      type = 'Pushed';
    }
    return type;
  }.property('model.type')
});
```

Handlebars doesn't have functions as you've written it, but since we are now using the event controller which wraps the single model, we just refer to interpretType to do the translation:

```
{{#each itemController='event'}}
  <li>{{interpretType}} to {{repo.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside an `Ember.ObjectController`

`ArrayController`'s deal with methods related to the collection of data from the model, whereas `ObjectController` deals with methods related to the specific object.

I'm also learning Ember from a Rails background.

If you haven't already come across this, you will definetely want to check out [ember-tools](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-tools), it's a command line generator very similar to what we've got in rails. I cant imagine building an Ember app without something like it..

Comment: Also, I believe you'll need to include the property required for the method to work properly. So `.property('type')` at the end

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Had to mark the other one because of the link to an updated JSBin, but I upvoted yours for the link to ember-tools. Super helpful!